# How can this equation $E=-p\ln\Big(\frac{1-p}{p}\Big)$ with $p \in [\frac{1}{2};1]$ be converted into a symmetric equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is done in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.04751.pdf) in section 4. I don't understand how they go from the first line to the second line of the derivation.
$$\begin{align}
E &= -p \ln\Big(\frac{1-p}{p}\Big)\\
&\Leftrightarrow -p \ln (1-p^2)
\end{align}$$

Comment: He says "Assuming that the perceived signal $(1 − p)/p$ is equal to the actual signal $p$," which requires $p$ to be the reciprocal or perhaps negative of the golden ratio so $\approx 0.618$  or perhaps $\approx -1.618$, and you would then have  $(1 − p)/p = p = 1-p^2$

Comment: $p=1/\phi$, one over the golden ratio?

Comment: @BobDobbs Yes - the paper is titled "The Golden Ratio of Learning and Momentum" so unlikely to be a coincidence

Comment: Then E stands for the Energy. @Henry

Comment: Thanks @Henry that makes sense!